# Some space below a tab bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a view with tab bars and I want some space below the tab bar to show some other content, at the bottom of the screen.

**Using Tab bar controller:**
When I use tab bar controller, the tab bar cannot be moved to place another object below it.

**Using Tab bar and tab bar items:**
When I use just tab bar and tab bar items, I am unable to connect the items to another view controller or rather anything. Also it doesn’t seem very efficient when my app has multiple tabs.

What is the best and efficient way to achieve some space at the bottom of the screen with tab bar controller?

Below is an image showing “some space” at the bottom of the screen below the tab bar.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed the tab bar controller in a custom parent view controller. Now the frame of the tab bar controller's view, relative to the custom parent view controller's view, is up to you.

This example was configured entirely in the storyboard, with no code at all:

[image]

Comment: How to embed in a custom parent view controller? I tried embedding but for tab bar controller it does not give any embed option. If you could walk through the steps it’ll be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: Start with a View Controller. Give it a Container View. Delete the embedded view controller that it gives you and make an embed segue from the Container View to a Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: I did that. But how do I put the extra space at the bottom of the screen? How do I put the other object below the tab bar? Also when I run the app, the view controller with container view will be the entry point?

Comment: "But how do I put the extra space at the bottom of the screen" Configure the Container View's constraints to allow the extra room and just put stuff into the space that that leaves. The entry point is whatever you declare as the entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your tabBarViewController

```swift
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        tabBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height-200, width: tabBar.frame.size.width, height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
        
    }
```

replace 200 with the distance you want your tab bar to be from the bottom of screen.

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle safe area insets properly.

Comment: this is a good solution until you have an headache about the safe area insets.